# How do I divide one inch in points to get ¼ inch?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, resolution

I want to resize an Image for printing at 300 resolution in Photoshop, to 2 1/4 inches × 2 1/4 inches (square) In the document size dialog box. How do I enter the correct numbers to get the desired 2 1/4 × 2 1/4 inch image size? How do I divide one inch in points to get the ¼ inch?

Comment: Why can't you just enter the size in inches? Why are you converting to points at all?

Comment: Because I need to also resize to 2.3/8 and the points help to come up to the right numbers for pixels. 1/8" of it inch is not easy to figure.

Comment: But you don't need to come up with the number of pixels, Photoshop does that for you... you just enter 2.25 x 2.25 inch and 300 ppi and your done

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Photoshop uses 72 points in an inch. So 1/4 inch equals 18 points. In your 2-1/4 x 2-1/4 inch example, resize to 162x162 points. If you are working in pixels, at a 300 ppi resolution, you'd resize to 675x675 pixels.

Comment: Thank you so much Dan! good job I double check it in Photoshop & bingo...

Comment: @Dion: welcome to Graphic Design! You may want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) in the [Help].

Comment: Hi Dan, I still can't get it on the next one: how do I get to print a 2-3/8" X 2-3/8" in pixels to enter in point? (300 resolution) (Please)